# Custom number format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Excel and need to define a custom number format.

```
If cell's value is 1 -> display "1"
If cell's value is 1.123 -> display "1.12"
If cell's value is 1.126 -> display "1.13"
If cell's value is 1324.126 -> display "1,324.13"
```

I use format code "#,###.00" but not correct. If value is 1 -> display "1.00"

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use macro. Only format code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Apply a default format of "#,###.00"
2. Add a conditional format
   `=INT(A1)=A1`
   with a format of a Number with no decimal places

The condtional format checks whether the cell is an integer only, if `True` the conditional format overides the default format of "#,###.00"

Comment: Hi, you use a fixed cell (A1) and only apply conditional format on it. However, I want to apply on a range of cells. How to do this. Thanks.

Comment: @LuLu you can apply this approach to an entire range, when you do it a) select the range from the top left cell b) add the formula with a reference to that top cell. ie for B7:C200 the formula would be `=INT(B7)=B7` as this would apply a relative formula to each cell, ie B10 would have a test of `=INT(B10)=B10` etc